# jersey single path multiple class implementation (selecting one instance programatically) similary to conditional dependency injection

Tags: java, web-services, dependency-injection, jersey

I have 3 **server-mode (1,2,3)** in a web application, for each server-mode a controller class with **same path** (/abc) is there.

ex: *abc1.class, abc2.class, abc3.class  and all the class inherits abc interface*

Server mode will be decided on server startup by reading a conf file.

Q1. My problem is i can't remove those controller classes on build time. Now based on the server mode say 2 then instance of abc2 class should be point for the path **/abc**.

Q2. This is same for service classes(100+ similar service & controller class are there) as well.
@Inject should get instance of abc, based on server mode.

I am new to jersey. what i learn is @Qualifier, @Priority, InjectionPoint but non of them suite my case (with my understanding)

My idea (for Q2) is to create a common layer(@CustomInject) to done this dependency injection,

By creating an annotation "ServerMode(value (1|2|3)" add them in those classes, based on the value/server-mode, instance of requested Class-Type can be returned from this common layer

(similar to inherit @inject & @any loop the available instance & then return desire one based on servermode from this common layer)

Is this possible? if so how to achieve it (for Q1 & Q2), any better predefined way/ annotation is there ?

thanks for you time & help

Comment: If the different server mode classes are in different packages, you can just use Jersey's package scanning to scan the package of the right server mode

Comment: @PaulSamsotha base packages are common, tried that but not suit my requirement. thanks for answer.

Comment: This is something you will have to do manually. Just create your own annotation and scan your resource classes and conditionally register them based on the annotation value. Check out [this library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520339/2587435) for some help scanning. See example use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52564924/2587435) where it scans looking for an annotation on a class.